# How to mock db ping without sqlmock

Tags: database, go, mocking

I would like to understand how to refactor my code to mock `db.Ping()` using `mock.Mock` for example. I would like to understand the concept without a framework first.

Here is the code I want to test:

```
func Connect() (*sql.DB, error) {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:secret@tcp(s-maria-db)/s_db")

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for i := 0; i < 60; i++ {
        // I am hoping to mock this portion
        if err := db.Ping(); err == nil {
            break
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }

    return db, nil
}
```

I attempted this post [How to mock a ping command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723476/how-to-mock-a-ping-command), but this has not actually answered the question. If it does, I do not understand the solution as it applies to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a separate function for pinging, and it needs to accept an interface so you can conditionally pass in a real `*sql.DB` or a mock. This is because you can't override a method on a struct.

```golang
// Connect opens a connection to the database.
func Connect() (*sql.DB, error) {
    return sql.Open("mysql", "root:secret@tcp(s-maria-db)/s_db")
}

// Pinger defines an interface for pinging.
type Pinger interface {
    Ping() error
}

// Ping attempts to ping the database, trying several times before failing.
func Ping(p Pinger) error {
    const maxAttempts = 60
    var err error
    for i := 0; i < maxAttempts; i++ {
        if err = p.Ping(); err == nil {
            return nil
        }
        if i < maxAttempts - 1 {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }
    return err
}
```

```golang
func main() {
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func run() error {
    db, err := Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("connecting to db: %w", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    if err = Ping(db); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("pinging db: %w", err)
    }
    
    ...
}
```

```golang
type mockDB struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *mockDB) Ping() error {
    args := m.Called()
    return args.Error(0)
}

func TestPing(t *testing.T) {
    db := &mockDB{}
    db.On("Ping").Return(...)

    err := Ping(db)

    ...
    db.AssertExpectations(t)
}
```

Comment: Continued with this link https://medium.com/yemeksepeti-teknoloji/mocking-an-interface-using-mockery-in-go-afbcb83cc773 for more learning.